# How to use Windows batch file to create a Txt file on a sony device SD card

Tags: android, shell, batch-file, adb

I am trying to automate a txt file to be created and installed to an android phone.

Hi, I have created a batch file to automate a script, setting up a Sony device. The script works fine and is great, however I am now trying to create a Txt file that stores information of the version and date that the device was scripted within the internal memory.

So far, all I need to do is set the device to developer mode, enable USB debugging then double click the windows batch file and it runs as expected. the list of commands follow as such:

```bash
\
shell input tap 0358 1108 #all apps\
shell input tap 0610 0802 #settings\
shell input tap 0343 0427 #wifi\
shell input tap 0674 0101 #3 dots\
shell input tap 0437 0290 #advanced\
shell input tap 0630 0252 #network notification off \
shell input keyevent 4 #back\
shell input keyevent 4 #exit\
shell input tap 0350 0552 #bluetooth\
shell input tap 0635 0212 #on\
shell input keyevent 4 #exit\
shell input tap 0357 0871 #more\
shell input tap 0340 0410 #android beam\
shell input tap 0648 0198 #off .........
```

This continues further and again works great. What I am trying to achieve is that the script creates a Txt files within the SD card, so I can refer back to which version the script used in the many months to come. So far I can achieve the following by manually opening CMD.

```bash
adb shell \
shell@F3311:/ $ echo "#Sony_Script \t#Version 1.0 \n\n \t\t#08/11/2022" > /sdcard/Android/data/ScriptVersion.txt
```

This creates the file as expected within the directory. However I haven't got the time to do this manually for every device and would like this automated but it never seems to work.

I don't want to open adb shell every time to do this, I am hoping to implement it within the original batch file so it can run in the background. I hope this makes sense. Below is the windows batch file I have created.

```bash
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION\
@echo off

REM adb command to grab all connected devices

adb devices > adb.txt
findstr /v "List of devices attached" adb.txt > clean.txt

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (Version.txt) do (
    for /f "tokens=1" %%b in (clean.txt) do (
        echo adb -s %%b %%a
        start adb -s %%b %%a
    )

    TIMEOUT /T 4
)
```

Comment: Please don't talk about an Sd Card as /sdcard/.. is just external memory (which is in the device) which has nothing to do with a removable micro sd card as you should know.

Comment: If you are going to send a file to the device, why don't you send the entire script and save tons of `shell`s being executed plus you achieve your versioning goal immediately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintain a script with version, something like

```
:
#Sony_Script    
#Version 1.0
#08/11/2022
input tap 0358 1108 #all apps
input tap 0610 0802 #settings
input tap 0343 0427 #wifi
input tap 0674 0101 #3 dots
input tap 0437 0290 #advanced
input tap 0630 0252 #network notification off
...
```

then

```
adb push myscript /sdcard/
adb shell sh /sdcard/myscript
```

you will know exactly what was executed on each device

Comment: Hi Diego, Thank you for the input. I have made a "commands" file to execute the shell input with the version# as you have done above. I then created a new text file to be executed using the batch file to adb push commands. However this does not seem to work. I really like your idea and approach and will work on this, so thank you. simple and effective.

Comment: I have tried using CMD to execute adb puch commands, but it is saying there is no such file or directory

Comment: Can you show the exact message? To know which is the file or directory not found.

Comment: adb push commands /sdcard
adb: error: cannot stat 'commands': No such file or directory

Comment: so just to be clear, I am trying to push the Txt file named 'commands' using CMD, both of which are in the same directory, even when I put the local directory, it still comes up with this error.

Comment: Is there no way to just 'echo' the script version through the commands while the batch is running?

Comment: your current directory might not containg `commands` file, try using the absolute path `adb push /path/to/commands /sdcard/`

Comment: Hi Diego, Yes I have already tried this but still came up with the same error. I even changed the name of the file, but that didn't help.